# routing files with zeromq (jeromq)

Tags: zeromq, jeromq

I'm trying to implement a "file dispatcher" on zmq (actually jeromq, I'd rather avoid jni).

What I need is to load balance incoming files to processors:

- each file is handled only by one processor
- files are potentially large so I need to manage the file transfer

Ideally I would like something like https://github.com/zeromq/filemq but

- with a push/pull behaviour rather than publish/subscribe
- being able to handle the received file rather than writing it to disk

My idea is to use a mix of taskvent/tasksink and asyncsrv samples.

Client side:

- one PULL socket to be notified of a file to be processed
- one DEALER socket to handle the (async) file transfer chunk by chunk

Server side:

- one PUSH socket to dispatch incoming file (names)
- one ROUTER socket to handle file requests
- a few DEALER workers managing the file transfers for clients and connected to the router via an inproc proxy

My first question is: does this seem like the right way to go? Anything simpler maybe?

My second question is: my current implem gets stuck on sending out the actual file data.

- clients are notified by the server, and issue a request.
- the server worker gets the request, and writes the response back to the inproc queue but the response never seems to go out of the server (can't see it in wireshark) and the client is stuck on the poller.poll awaiting the response.

It's not a matter of sockets being full and dropping data, I'm starting with very small files sent in one go.

Any insight?

Thanks!

==================

Following raffian's advice I simplified my code, removing the push/pull extra socket (it does make sense now that you say it)

I'm left with the "non working" socket!

Here's my current code. It has many flaws that are out of scope for now (client ID, next chunk etc..)

For now, I'm just trying to have both guys talking to each other roughly in that sequence

- Server

  ```
  object FileDispatcher extends App
  {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)

    // server is the frontend that pushes filenames to clients and receives requests
    val server = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER)
    server.bind("tcp://*:5565")
    // backend handles clients requests
    val backend = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
    backend.bind("inproc://backend")

    // files to dispatch given in arguments
    args.toList.foreach { filepath =>
      println(s"publish $filepath")
      server.send("newfile".getBytes(), ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      server.send(filepath.getBytes(), 0)
    }

    // multithreaded server: router hands out requests to DEALER workers via a inproc queue
    val NB_WORKERS = 1
    val workers = List.fill(NB_WORKERS)(new Thread(new ServerWorker(context)))
    workers foreach (_.start)
    ZMQ.proxy(server, backend, null)
  }

  class ServerWorker(ctx: ZMQ.Context) extends Runnable 
  {
    override def run() 
    {
      val worker = ctx.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
      worker.connect("inproc://backend")

      while (true) 
      {
        val zmsg = ZMsg.recvMsg(worker) 
        zmsg.pop // drop inner queue envelope (?)
        val cmd = zmsg.pop //cmd is used to continue/stop
        cmd.toString match {
          case "get" => 
            val file = zmsg.pop.toString
            println(s"clientReq: cmd: $cmd , file:$file")
            //1- brute force: ignore cmd and send full file in one go!
            worker.send("eof".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE) //header indicates this is the last chunk
            val bytes = io.Source.fromFile(file).mkString("").getBytes //dirty read, for testing only!
            worker.send(bytes, 0)
            println(s"${bytes.size} bytes sent for $file: "+new String(bytes))
          case x => println("cmd "+x+" not implemented!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- client

  ```
  object FileHandler extends App
  {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)

    // client is notified of new files then fetches file from server
    val client = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
    client.connect("tcp://*:5565")
    val poller = new ZMQ.Poller(1) //"poll" responses
    poller.register(client, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)

    while (true) 
    {
      poller.poll
      val zmsg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client)
      val cmd = zmsg.pop
      val data = zmsg.pop
      // header is the command/action
      cmd.toString match {
        case "newfile" => startDownload(data.toString)// message content is the filename to fetch
        case "chunk" => gotChunk(data.toString, zmsg.pop.getData) //filename, chunk
        case "eof" => endDownload(data.toString, zmsg.pop.getData) //filename, last chunk
      }
    }

    def startDownload(filename: String) 
    {
      println("got notification: start download for "+filename)
      client.send("get".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE) //command header
      client.send(filename.getBytes, 0) 
    }

    def gotChunk(filename: String, bytes: Array[Byte]) 
    {
      println("got chunk for "+filename+": "+new String(bytes)) //callback the user here
      client.send("next".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      client.send(filename.getBytes, 0) 
    }

    def endDownload(filename: String, bytes: Array[Byte]) 
    {
      println("got eof for "+filename+": "+new String(bytes)) //callback the user here
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client, you don't need `PULL` with `DEALER`.
DEALER is `PUSH` and `PULL` combined, so use DEALER only, your code will be simpler.

Same goes for the server, unless you're doing something special, you don't need `PUSH` with `ROUTER`, router is bidirectional.

> the server worker gets the request, and writes the response back to
>   the inproc queue but the response never seems to go out of the server
>   (can't see it in wireshark) and the client is stuck on the poller.poll
>   awaiting the response.

### Code Problems

In the server, you're dispatching files with `args.toList.foreach` before starting the proxy, this is probably why nothing is leaving the server. Start the proxy first, then use it; Also, once you call `ZMQProxy(..)`, the code blocks indefinitely, so you'll need a separate thread to send the filepaths.

The client may have an issue with the poller. The typical pattern for polling is:

```
ZMQ.Poller items = new ZMQ.Poller (1);
items.register(receiver, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
while (true) {

  items.poll(TIMEOUT);
  if (items.pollin(0)) {
    message = receiver.recv(0);
```

In the above code, 1) poll until timeout, 2) then check for messages, and if available, 3) get with `receiver.recv(0)`. But in your code, you poll then drop into `recv()` without checking. You need to check if the poller has messages for that polled socket before calling `recv()`, otherwise, the receiver will hang if there's no messages.

Comment: thanks for your help raffian, i cleaned up the useless push/pull layer and posted some code.. my router is still silent, I must be missing something obvious..

Comment: You said you're using jero, but that's not java?

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally it starts to work :)

Indeed, for the first "publish" I thought I could directly write out on the router socket, but with the inproc queue it made no sense!

I changed to have the client initiate the dialog (with a hello msg) and send the next filename (from a queue) to the client who requests it. 

The code is in scala, so it works fine with jeromq.

Comment: Oh, so _that's_ scala?!? pretty cool, need to put that on my list of things to play with; how do you like it?

Comment: I thought I did accept it by clicking the green tick mark; anything else I need to click?

I LOVE scala! :)
If you're a java developer you'll soon start to wonder why you ever bothered with a language that cumbersome! (I've done 15 years of java, but honestly, it's almost 2014 now!)
To start with with, scala is just a much lighter java, then you can progressively introduce FP concepts that will really change the way you think your code.
If you can, I highly recommend Martin Odersky's free courses on coursera.com.

Cheers

Comment: @raffian could you please have an look on these questions [standby/active queue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40909865/1066779) and [ZMQueue class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41032230/1066779)