# what is the use of ZMQueue class in JeroMQ

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

I checked source code of **`ZMQueue`** class from JeroMQ which implements Runnable interface looks like:

```
private final Socket  inSocket;
private final Socket outSocket;

 public ZMQQueue( Context context, Socket inSocket, Socket outSocket ){
    this.inSocket  =  inSocket;
    this.outSocket = outSocket;
 }

 @Override
 public void run(){
        zmq.ZMQ.proxy( inSocket.base(), outSocket.base(), null );
 }
```

As you can see inside the **`run()`** only one statement is there, i.e. calling a

**`ZMQ.proxy()`** - what happens here?

And in constructor,
it's taking a `Context` instance as a parameter and doing nothing with it.

can any one explains, for what purpose this class has implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple proxy that works in separate thread, it takes a msg from one socket and puts it to another, ZMQueue class is just a some kind of high-level api in jeromq/jzmq library.

Also you can use proxy without ZMQueue class ([doc](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#ZeroMQ-s-Built-In-Proxy-Function)).
Or you can implement something more complicated by yourself with any processing you need.